# Allow editing tag info on iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, tag-wiki

Currently, when viewing tag-info in the Stack Exchange iOS app, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to suggest edits for tag info.

Why not have an action bar like the one on question pages?

[image: mockup comparison of tag edit bar]